# How i set width in percentages of columns of MX datagrid in flex?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to know how i set width in percentages of columns of MX datagrid in flex ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively to Jason Sturges' answer, you can actually just put in decimals and the datagrid figures it out.

`<mx:DataGridColumn width="0.4" />` would be 40%.

You can NOT mix and match with fixed widths. All columns must add up to 1.

Example:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn width="0.4" />
<mx:DataGridColumn width="0.6" />
```

This adds up to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate percent based upon width in the property attribute:

40%

```
<mx:DataGridColumn width="{0.4 * width}" />
```

60%

```
<mx:DataGridColumn width="{0.6 * width}" />
```

Comment: @jonathan-rowny has the right solution if all your columns are percentage based.